# Change text color inside box on hover

Tags: html, css

So right now self teaching myself so html and CSS and I have a slight problem. In my menu bar I have some list items that I want to change color when the mouse hovers over the box, but I'm unsure how to do that. Right now I have:

```
#Menu li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.5)
}

#Menu li a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

But this makes it where when I hover over the text it changes and only the box changes. I tried:

```
#Menu li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.5)
    color: black;
}
```

but that does nothing except change the box color. Also having a gradual change instead of an abrupt change would be nice as well.

```css
#Menu {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(255,165,0);

}
#Menu ul{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
}

#Menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:40px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size:16px;
}

#Menu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    position: fixed;

}

#Menu li:hover {
    background-color: #FFB733;

}

#Menu li a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="Menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Cat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mouse</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

edit: Added code snippet

Comment: Share a sample of the html.

Comment: @Flameancer if on `hover` you want to change the text color you have to write like `#Menu li:hover a{color: red;}` This code means when `hovering` over `li` , `a` anchor tag will also effected. check demo.  
http://jsbin.com/metihaneyu/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Menu li {
    transition: 2s;
}

#Menu li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
    color: red;
}
```

See the example http://jsfiddle.net/k35rdfhp/1/

The item change background-color and color when hover the box of item, not only the text.

Comment: No doubt this works, because I just tried it right now, but for some reason it doesn't work in mine and I have no idea why? Tried in 3 separate browsers as well.

Comment: @Flameancer sometimes other css code on the page may be interfering. If any property is not taking effect, try adding `!important` at the end of the property value.

Answer (score 0):

Try specify color for `#Menu li:hover a`  - http://jsfiddle.net/k35rdfhp/2/

```
#Menu li a:hover, #Menu li:hover a  {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified ASR's answer and added transitions to it.CSS3 has some built in animations that don't require javascript or other js libraries to use

```
#Menu li:hover {
    background-color: #FFB733;
    background: red;
    transition-property: background;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j863v3t7/